# C# equivalent on java constructor

Tags: c#, java, android

Not sure if my title is correct. Forgot what it is code. But here I will explain it through code.

You see in Java, you can declare a class like this:

```
class Panel extends View {

        public Bitmap mBitmap;

        public Panel(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
}
```

In C#:

```
class Panel : View
{
     public Panel(Context context)
     {
         base(context);
     }
}
```

it throws an error.

How do you declare a class constructor like that in C# ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Panel : View
{
    public Panel(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

[MSDN: Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

In C#, calling the base constructor is a bit more explicit (or rather explicitly separate)

While in Java it would look like just any statement that could be reordered with the other statements in the body, it's moved outside the normal constructor body in C#.

```
class Panel : View
{
    public Panel(Context context) : base(context) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for calling base class constructor in java is similar in c sharp. The main difference is the keyword `super` in Java, `base` in C# (with a colon).

These will call base class constructor to execute first then derived class

```
class Panel : View
{
     public Panel(Context context) : base(context)
     {
         // ...
     }
}
```